# Как должна выглядеть база данных для меню?

Tags: mysql, база-данных, phpmyadmin

Есть меню 1, допустим в нем содержится наименования фирм.
Меню 2 зависит от того, что я выбрал в меню 1, там допустим содержатся отросли фирм.
В меню 3 выводится информация которую получает человек исходя из своего выбора. Допустим в меню 3 - товары. Допустим нужно, что бы была возможность несколько отраслей.
Интересует структура БД в данном случае.
Как я понимаю отдельная таблица для меню 1, для меню 2. Потом еще одна таблица, что бы сделать связь, что к какому меню относится. Или хватит одной таблицы с perentID? И как тогда выводить товар? То же через несколько таблиц связывать? Посоветуйте пожалуйста
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]